# How to prove that this infinite extension of $\mathbb{Q}$ is Galois

Tags: galois-theory

Let $K_0=\mathbb{Q}$ and for $n>0$ define $K_{n+1}$ as the extension of $K_n$ obtained by adjoining to $K_n$ all the radicals of elements in $K_n$. Let $K$ be the union of the subfields $K_n$.

Prove that $K$ is a Galois extension of $\mathbb{Q}$.

By definition, $K_{n+1}/K_n$ is algebraic, hence separable ($char\mathbb{Q}=0 )$

I do not know how to prove the normality.

Comment: Some information that might be superfluous:
Let $F$ be the normal closure of $K$ over $\mathbb{Q}$. Since $K$ is separable over $\mathbb{Q}$, $F$ is Galois over $\mathbb{Q}$.
It is immediate that $K$ has no nontrivial radical extensions. I think this could be used to show that $K$ has no nontrivial Galois extension (but I'm not sure).
Since $F/K$ is Galois, it follows $F=K$

Comment: What do you mean precisely by "adjoining all radicals"? In my (probably wrong) interpretation, we have $K=K_1$.

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg If we adjoin to $\bf Q$ all $k$th roots of all rational numbers for all naturals $k$, does that automatically give us all nested radicals too?

Comment: Ah ok I see, we have $\sqrt[a]{\sqrt[b]{x}}=\sqrt[ab]{x}$, but we cannot do this for $\sqrt[a]{\sqrt[b]{x}+\sqrt[c]{y}}$ for example.

Answer (score 1):

We have to show that every homomorphism $\phi : K \to \overline{\mathbb{Q}}$ factors through $K$ (this is equivalent to normality). In fact we can prove $\phi(K_n) \subseteq K_n$ by induction on $n$. For $n=0$ this is clear, and for $n \leadsto n+1$ let $a \in K_{n+1}$, wlog a radical from some element $K_n$, i.e. there is some $d \geq 1$ with $a^d \in K_n$. It follows $\phi(a)^d = \phi(a^d) \in \phi(K_n) \subseteq K_n$, and therefore $\phi(a) \in K_{n+1}$.

By the way, the main result of Galois theory implies that $K$ is the compositum of all finite solvable Galois extensions of $\mathbb{Q}$ (i.e. those with solvable Galois group), sometimes denoted by $\mathbb{Q}^{\mathrm{solv}}$. See [MO/4379](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/4379/solvable-class-field-theory) for some information about it. It follows that $\mathrm{Gal}(\mathbb{Q}^\mathrm{solv}/\mathbb{Q})$ is the maximal pro-solvable quotient of $\mathrm{Gal}(\overline{\mathbb{Q}}/\mathbb{Q})$. I wonder if this profinite group  has been classified?

Comment: Yes, I was completely wrong. I was taking $K_{n+1}$ as the extension of $K_n$ obtained by adjoining to $K_n$ all the elements that can be solved by radicals of elements in $K_n$. However, it seems to be a good question. By the way, Has K a nontrivial Galois extension?

Comment: Sure, $\overline{\mathbb{Q}}/K$.